# yarn test(jest) finds no tests with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am fairly new to automated testing in JavaScript and wanted to include Jest in my work.

I followed a simple guide for Jest-Testing in create-react-app.

When I try to run my test with *yarn test*, it starts in watch mode without any errors and then gives me :

```
No tests found, exiting with code 0
```

My testfile is in src/*.spec.ts. 
I tried *.test.js, put it in src/__test__/(*.js | *.ts).

I could not figure out, why it does not find any test.

So I created a completely new react app:

```
yarn create react-app test --typescript
cd .\test
yarn test
```

And it gave me the exact same error (no tests found) with a plain new create-react-app. Tried it with and without typescript.

I installed jest globally and tried to test with just *jest* as command in my project folder. It finds the tests like it should, but it has syntax errors with the first JSX statement:

```
      4 |
      5 | test('renders learn react link', () => {
    > 6 |   const { getByText } = render(<App />);
        |                                ^
      7 |   const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);
      8 |   expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
      9 | });
```

The *package.json* from the fresh create-react-app looks like this for me:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am on Windows10 right now.
I found many errors describing my problem but it seems there was such a thing with Jest 22/23 because of micropatterns, while I am on Jest 25.2.1 and a fresh install. None of the provided solutions worked for me.
Since I am completely new to jest I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

It shows that you have syntax errors in your test, because your test file has jsx inside of it and is named `.ts`, but it should be `.tsx`

Comment: The file is named **App.test.tsx** and is in this case the standard file which comes with a fresh *create react-app*.

Comment: @sdobedev I know I'm over a year late, but did you solve this...? It's so frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

@Cookie I don't remember exactly what the problem itself was in the end, but maybe my current `setupTests.ts` can help out here:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

module.exports = {
  // The root of your source code, typically /src
  // `<rootDir>` is a token Jest substitutes
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],

  // Jest transformations -- this adds support for TypeScript
  // using ts-jest
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },

  // Runs special logic, such as cleaning up components
  // when using React Testing Library and adds special
  // extended assertions to Jest
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '@testing-library/react/cleanup-after-each',
    '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect',
  ],

  // Test spec file resolution pattern
  // Matches parent folder `__tests__` and filename
  // should contain `test` or `spec`.
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',

  // Module file extensions for importing
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json'],
};
```

All my tests are in `src/__tests__`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding arguments to test script in `package.json` helped for me:

```
"test": "react-scripts test --testMatch '**/*.test.js' '**/*.test.ts' '**/*.test.jsx' '**/*.test.tsx'"
```